# Не достается часть кода python

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, beautiful-soup

я далеко не гуру питона и тем более парсеров, но теперь работа обязывает разбираться. Поставлена задача из сайта вытащить всю контактную информацию, и все бы хорошо, но не могу никак достать адрес по строке :

119021, 
                                                                                г. Москва,
                                                                                Несвижский пер.,
                                                                                д. 10

Подскажите, может кто-нибудь сталкивался или может подсказать, что в таком случае делать? Используются стандартные библиотеки BeautifulSoup, pandas, numpy, requests через find и get.

Буду очень признательна за помощь!

Ссылка для примера : https://pravotop.ru/company/2leks

[image: Вот так выглядит код на сайте]

```py
url = 'pravotop.ru/company/2leks' 
page = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml') 
inf = soup.find('div', class_ = 'contacts-column') 
adress = inf.find('p', class_ = 'address').get('br/')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте ваш код.

Comment: Все достается с помощью BeautifulSoup + requests , гайдов полный вагон и маленькая тележка на просторах интернета.

Comment: @СергейШ Через них и работаю, и если бы все было просто я бы не писала вопрос, но спасибо за комментарий

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn конкретно этот кусок пыталась достать с помощью                                           url = 'https://pravotop.ru/company/2leks'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
inf = soup.find('div', class_ = 'contacts-column')
adress = inf.find('p', class_ = 'address').get('br/')

Comment: adress = soup.find(class_ = 'address').text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как верно отметил @СергейШ, найти элемент можно по классу `address`- он уникальный на странице. Но, добыв текст, получаем "в нагрузку" пару вагонов пробелов и 5 переводов строк (пробелы визуализировал тильдами):

```
\n
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~119021,~\n
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~г.~Москва,\n
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Несвижский~пер.,\n
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~д.~10\n
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Чтобы убрать ненужные пробельные символы и получить удобоваримый адрес в одну строку, разделенную одиночными пробелами, можно применить сначала `split()` без аргументов (он считает несколько подряд идущих пробельных символов одним разделителем), затем `' '.join()`. Вариантом "чистки" строки могут быть регулярные выражения, но это более громоздко.
Полный код решения:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://pravotop.ru/company/2leks'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
adress = ' '.join(soup.find(class_='address').get_text().split())
print(adress)
```

```
119021, г. Москва, Несвижский пер., д. 10
```

Answer (score 1):

необходимо получить данные из тега `<p>` с классом `address`, для этого можно использовать `tree.xpath("//p[@class='address']//text()")`, но т.к. данные в теге разбиты на несколько из-за использования `<br>`, то данные надо соединить через `" ".join()`

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
import requests
parser = etree.HTMLParser( )
page = requests.get('https://pravotop.ru/company/2leks')
html = page.content.decode("utf-8")
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(html), parser=parser)

addr = " ".join(tree.xpath("//p[@class='address']//text()"))

print(addr)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]